# Best way to copy a file from /proc to another location from C++ code?

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

As part of my C++ program, I want to copy `/proc/self/mountinfo` elsewhere. However, `std::filesystem::copy_file()` does not seem to work with files in this directory.

What's the easiest, safest way to do this? Besides just opening the file, reading it into a string, then writing it out elsewhere.

Comment: Check permissions

Comment: What happens when you try to copy it? I think it should be treated as a regular file by most applications.

Comment: @lorro It's not a disk file, `/proc` is a virtual filesystem. Everything in `/proc/self` should be readable by the process.

Comment: I can `cp` it just fine but std::filesystem::copy_file just gives me an empty file. Is that expected? Couldn’t find anything about how copy_file handles virtual FS files.

Comment: std::filesystem::copy_file in Linux implemented via sendfile(). sendfile() requires size to copy. Files under /proc have no size. Just open your file, create destination file and read/write blocks until can read from source file.